# Collaborative text editing with Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I have a relatively full-featured Django application which already works with Django Channels for live page updates and on-page live chat (Redis channel layer backend). If it is relevant I also have Celery working in the background to synchronise data with external APIs.

I am trying to allow site visitors to collaboratively edit text on various pages (with some formatting preferred). I'd like to store the data using the Django ORM (I am using a Postgres DB) and don't need offline editing capability.

Is anyone familiar with a possible solution here? I have been searching for a long time and most solutions require alternative full 'stacks'. Ideally I can use something that already leverages the existing Django Channels Websocket connection.

I have found these options so far:

- [Firepad](https://firepad.io/) - Requires a connection to a Firebase server (and therefore another account)
- [Codox.io](https://www.codox.io/) - Initial set-up didn't work and would prefer not to pay an additional subscription fee
- [ShareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb) - Looks great, especially with the in-memory implementation. I just don't know how to integrate with Django Channels!

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.